# Match ID's in Multiple Columns in a DataFrame to Another DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

Okay so I have a DataFrame **DF1**
that looks like:

| contents | posts | tags | impressions | clicks | reactions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| video | instagram | [{'id': 87524}, {'id': 91824}] | 23 | 65 | 42 |
| Picture | Facebook | [{'id': 91824}, {'id': 87524}] | 54 | 63 | 21 |
| Reel | instagram | [{'id': 76241}, {'id': 12348}, {'id': 87524}] | 24 | 86 | 24 |
| Video | Twitter | 0 | 57 | 54 | 76 |
| Text | Twitter | [{'id': 1141696}] | 24 | 65 | 87 |

And I have another dataframe **DF2** that looks like:

| Tags | Campaigns |
| --- | --- |
| 87524 | Boston |
| 91824 | Los Angeles |
| 76241 | Las Vegas |
| 12348 | New York |
| 1141696 | Seattle |

I want to match the tags in DF2 with the tags in DF1 and ideally get a table like

| contents | posts | tags | impressions | clicks | reactions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| video | instagram | Boston, Los Angeles] | 23 | 65 | 42 |
| Picture | Facebook | Los Angeles, Boston | 54 | 63 | 21 |
| Reel | instagram | Las Vegas, New York, Boston] | 24 | 86 | 24 |
| Video | Twitter | 0 | 57 | 54 | 76 |
| Text | Twitter | Seattle | 24 | 65 | 87 |

My Attempt:

I was thinking of getting the nested JSON inside the tag column to open individually and have separate columns. Then use merge to add DF2 into the DF1. The problem is

1)When I am trying to open up tags, I use **ast.literal_eval** like here:

```
import ast
df1['internal.tags']=df1['internal.tags'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

but I get this error:
**'ValueError: malformed node or string: nan'**

I think that is because of the '0' inside the dataframe which doesn't let the literal_eval to do its thing but I am not sure.

2)My second problem is that when I get all the tags into individual columns, how can I merge the DF2 into the however many columns we get from the tags. Is there a way around it? Maybe another option

THANK YOU SO MUCH AND ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Force them all to strings first:

```
df['tags'] = df['tags'].astype(str).apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

2. Explode, then extract:

```
df = df.explode('tags')
df['tags'] = df['tags'].str['id']
print(df.tail())
```

```
  contents      posts       tags  impressions  clicks  reactions
2     Reel  instagram    76241.0           24      86         24
2     Reel  instagram    12348.0           24      86         24
2     Reel  instagram    87524.0           24      86         24
3    Video    Twitter        NaN           57      54         76
4     Text    Twitter  1141696.0           24      65         87
```

3. Make column names match for convenience, and Merge:

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Tags':'tags'})
out = df.merge(df2, on='tags', how='left')
print(out.head())
```

```
  contents      posts     tags  impressions  clicks  reactions    Campaigns
0    video  instagram  87524.0           23      65         42       Boston
1    video  instagram  91824.0           23      65         42  Los Angeles
2  Picture   Facebook  91824.0           54      63         21  Los Angeles
3  Picture   Facebook  87524.0           54      63         21       Boston
4     Reel  instagram  76241.0           24      86         24    Las Vegas
```

4. Aggregate again:

```
out = out.groupby(['contents', 'posts', 'impressions', 'clicks', 'reactions'], as_index=False)['Campaigns'].agg(list)
# or out.fillna('').groupby(['contents', 'posts', 'impressions', 'clicks', 'reactions'], as_index=False)['Campaigns'].agg(', '.join)
print(out)
```

```
  contents      posts  impressions  clicks  reactions                      Campaigns
0  Picture   Facebook           54      63         21          [Los Angeles, Boston]
1     Reel  instagram           24      86         24  [Las Vegas, New York, Boston]
2     Text    Twitter           24      65         87                      [Seattle]
3    Video    Twitter           57      54         76                          [nan]
4    video  instagram           23      65         42          [Boston, Los Angeles]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I had trouble with literal_eval as I had a few 0 values. So I used a try-except exception with a for loop which runs smoothly. This was definitely in the right direction and i really appreciate it!